# Cortana Windows 10 UWP Integration - Using {*} in VCD

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, cortana, vcd

In the [specification for vcd files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn706593), it says that {*} is used to match anything. However for he example command:

```
<Command Name="addFoodLog">
      <Example> I had a burger for lunch </Example>
      <!--Recording a drink-->
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> [I] drank [a] {*} with [my] {mealtime} </ListenFor>
      <!--Recording a meal-->
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> [I] ate [a] {*} for [my] {mealtime} </ListenFor>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> [I'm] having {*} for [my] {mealtime} </ListenFor>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> [I] [just] had [a] {*} for {mealtime} </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Recording your {mealtime}</Feedback>
      <Navigate />
</Command>
```

Printing the result of this input will be `I drank a ... with my dinner`

Is there any way to get what was actually said out of the text? Or perhaps this is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a phrase topic then you'll solve your problem as it will pick up a larger vocabulary.

Heres an example:

```
<PhraseTopic Label="food">
  <Subject>Food</Subject>
  <Subject>Drink</Subject>
  <Subject>Meal</Subject>
  <Subject>Food</Subject>
</PhraseTopic>
```

Checkout the [Voice Command Definition elements and attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn722331.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Below is how you can get a search term, not from a list of values. This is for HTML/JS, as opposed to XAML, but should give you a good idea.

**The XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
    <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="FNOW_en-us">
        <AppName> YourAppName </AppName>
        <Example> Search books </Example>

        <Command Name="SearchFor">
            <Example> Search for Harry Potter </Example>
            <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> find book {SearchTerm} </ListenFor>
            <Feedback> Searching books </Feedback>
            <Navigate />
        </Command>

        <PhraseTopic Label="SearchTerm" Scenario="Search"/>
    </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
function handleVoiceCommand(args) {
    var command,
        commandResult,
        commandName = '',
        commandProperties = {};

    if (args.detail && args.detail.detail) {
        command = args.detail.detail[0];

        if (command) {
            commandResult = command.result;

            if (commandResult) {
                if (commandResult.rulePath) {
                    commandName = commandResult.rulePath[0];
                }
                if (commandResult.semanticInterpretation) {
                    commandProperties = commandResult.semanticInterpretation.properties;
                }

                // Act on the different commands.
                // Command Names are defined within VoiceCommands.xml.
                switch(commandName) {
                    case 'SearchFor':
                        console.log('Cortana Command: SearchFor');
                        console.log('Search Term: ' + commandProperties.SearchTerm[0]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

WinJS.Application.addEventListener('activated', function (args) {
    var appLaunchVoiceCommand;

    appLaunchVoiceCommand = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand || 16;
    if (args.detail.kind === appLaunchVoiceCommand) {
        return handleVoiceCommand(args);
    }
});

WinJS.Application.start();
```